# Removing a subarray after using numpy.split

Tags: python, numpy

Title kinda says it all, I'm trying to make two new matrices after using numpy.split, so:

```
#A is some mxn matrix
numfolds=5
folds = numpy.split(A,numfolds)
#now folds is 5 equalish subarrays which can be called out
#subarray1 is the second fold (the second fifth of A along axis=0 by default)
subarray1 = folds[2]
#numpy.delete does not get rid of the second subarray in A
arrayWithoutSubArray1 = numpy.concatenate(numpy.delete(folds[2]))
```

How do a make a matrix which is all but one subarray in A, in this example. I'd rather not use loops. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mea culpa, it's numpy.split.

Comment: `np.delete` doesn't do in-situ changes. So, you need to assign it back.

Comment: Ok I think that fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @T.Welsh Then please delete the question, as it doesn't have any answer involved and this question won't be any useful to any user in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

The solution is to do the delete outside of the concatenate and index properly.

```
#A is some mxn matrix
numfolds=5
folds = numpy.split(A,numfolds)
#now folds is 5 equalish subarrays which can be called out
#subarray1 is the second fold (the second fifth of A along axis=0 by default)
subarray1 = folds[2]
#numpy.delete does not get rid of the second subarray in A
arrayWithoutSubArray1 = numpy.delete(folds,2,0)
arrayWithoutSubArray1 = numpy.concatenate(arrayWithoutSubArray1)
```